# Disable tap-to-click on login screen

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, greeter, touchpad

How can I disable tap-to-click in the greeter/login screen of elementaryOS?

I know that I can disable tap-to-click on a desktop of a user in the settings dialogue of mouse and touchpad. In the command line this is done using e.g. gsettings.

However, as a user tap-to-click is disabled for my users and I can check that with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click
false
```

But I fail doing it for the greeter having an annoying behaviour of the UI when typing in passwords.

---

I found that 
[my question here duplicates this launchpad bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-mouse-touchpad/+bug/1605247). <del>However, may be someone finds a workaround faster than me ;)</del> However, I upgraded to Loki, but am still somehow interested in finding how to change the tapping behaviour in the greeter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a palm detection method
Try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_while_typing

Comment: I once saw this tip. However, recently I upgraded to Loki. There the problem does not exist anymore. Why? I do not know: In the packages (now Loki) I search, there is no 'xf86-input-synaptics'. Therefore I do not find '70-synaptics.conf' in '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/'. And '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/' does not exist - only '/etc/X11/Xsession.d'.

Comment: You can create '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/', then 50-synaptics.conf

Comment: Actually it doen't matter how you name config file because the whole 'xorg.conf.d' directory was created for these 'somename.conf' files just to split for the sake of simplicity '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' which is for all X server settings.